# Use elementFromPoint combined with scroll position

Tags: javascript

I would ask for help for the following problem. Given is a long list of divs with names. Each div with a name has a data-index with the initial letter of that person.

A small div sticked to the scrollbar indicator should name the initial letter from the current person next to it (Indicated by the blue line). Further the Text inside the div should be styled red otherwise black and the header of 100px should be respected

This is what I have:

```js
window.onscroll = function(event){
    // Variables for scroll pos calculation
    var viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    var scrolledAmount = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var indicatorTop = scrolledAmount * viewPortHeight / documentHeight;

    // Highlight current active name and get data attr
    // THIS PART IS NOT WORKING
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(0, scrolledAmount);
    el.style.color = 'red';
    var el_text = el.dataset.index;
  
    // Stick the index div to the scrollbar
    if (indicatorTop > 110) {
      document.getElementById('index').style.marginTop = indicatorTop-110+'px';
      document.getElementById('line').style.marginTop = indicatorTop-110+'px';
      document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = el_text;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('index').style.marginTop = '0px';
      document.getElementById('line').style.marginTop = '0px';
    }
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  
}
.person__wrapper {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.person__item {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 90%
}

#index, #line{
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: ClarendonBT-Heavy
}

#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0
}

.header__wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
    
}
```

```html
<header class="header__wrapper"></header>

<section class="person__wrapper">
<article data-index="A" class="person__item">Adam</article>
<article data-index="B" class="person__item">Bobby</article>
<article data-index="C" class="person__item">Carla</article>
<article data-index="D" class="person__item">Debby</article>
<article data-index="E" class="person__item">Emil</article>
<article data-index="F" class="person__item">F</article>
<article data-index="G" class="person__item">G</article>
<article data-index="H" class="person__item">H</article>
<article data-index="I" class="person__item">I</article>
<article data-index="J" class="person__item">J</article>
<article data-index="K" class="person__item">K</article>
<article data-index="L" class="person__item">L</article>
<article data-index="M" class="person__item">M...</article>
<article data-index="N" class="person__item">N...</article>
<article data-index="O" class="person__item">O...</article>
<article data-index="P" class="person__item">P...</article>
<article data-index="Q" class="person__item">Q...</article>
<article data-index="R" class="person__item">R...</article>
<article data-index="S" class="person__item">S...</article>
<article data-index="T" class="person__item">T...</article>
<article data-index="U" class="person__item">U...</article>
<article data-index="V" class="person__item">V...</article>
<article data-index="W" class="person__item">W...</article>
<article data-index="X" class="person__item">X...</article>
<article data-index="Y" class="person__item">Y...</article>
<article data-index="Z" class="person__item">Z...</article>
</section>


<div id="index">A</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://codepen.io/t-book/pen/zYvZzxV

All is working fine except `elementFromPoint` is not targeting the element which has the y amount of my scrolled height but all elements (all get red). Further, the data attribute is not updated inside by index div.

Can one push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found your question while searching a problem of my own. Little stale, but if you're still looking for a solution maybe this will help. There were a few issues going on:

- [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) uses coordinates relative to the viewport, not the document. So using a y value of `scrolledAmount` probably wasn't doing what you really wanted. `0` would be the top of the viewport. More on this in a bit.
- but...since the header is fixed, it always gets returned. Two ways to solve this. The easiest is to add css `pointer-events:none` on the header. Then it gets ignored. But if you need pointer events, the alternative would be to use `elementsFromPoint` which will return an array, and you can skip the `header` and grab the next element in the array.
- since you've got a margin on your items, when the margin passes over the point you're querying it "falls through" to the underlying `section` tag. Unfortunately the best way around this seems to be a short `for` loop that can move the point slightly until you find the next `article` tag, and break the loop as soon as a match is found. (I wish there was a better way...that's what I was looking for when I found your question!)
- I'm also using an `x` coord of `window.innerWidth/2` for the same reason, to get past left margins and such. Of course this could be tweaked to meet your needs.
- the reason why all of the headers were turning red is because fairly quickly after you started scrolling, your `elementFromPoint` was falling through and hitting a higher level element. And since `color` is an inherited property, it was being applied on all the `article`s as children. This can be prevented by the `.closest('article')` thing I added. That way if it's not an `article` or a descendant of an `article`, it will be null...not the wrong element.

```js
window.onscroll = function(event) {
  // Variables for scroll pos calculation
  var viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  var scrolledAmount = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var indicatorTop = scrolledAmount * viewPortHeight / documentHeight;

  // Highlight current active name and get data attr
  for (var i = 0; i < 80; i += 10) {
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(window.innerWidth / 2, i).closest('article');
    if (el) break;
  }
  if (el) {
    el.style.color = 'red';
    var el_text = el.dataset.index;
  }

  document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = el_text || 'A';

  // Stick the index div to the scrollbar
  if (indicatorTop > 110) {
    document.getElementById('index').style.marginTop = indicatorTop - 110 + 'px';
    document.getElementById('line').style.marginTop = indicatorTop - 110 + 'px';

  } else {
    document.getElementById('index').style.marginTop = '0px';
    document.getElementById('line').style.marginTop = '0px';
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.person__wrapper {
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.person__item {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#index,
#line {
  position: fixed;
  top: 110px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #0000ff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: ClarendonBT-Heavy
}

#line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.header__wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<header class="header__wrapper" style="pointer-events:none"></header>

<section class="person__wrapper">
  <article data-index="A" class="person__item">Adam</article>
  <article data-index="B" class="person__item">Bobby</article>
  <article data-index="C" class="person__item">Carla</article>
  <article data-index="D" class="person__item">Debby</article>
  <article data-index="E" class="person__item">Emil</article>
  <article data-index="F" class="person__item">F</article>
  <article data-index="G" class="person__item">G</article>
  <article data-index="H" class="person__item">H</article>
  <article data-index="I" class="person__item">I</article>
  <article data-index="J" class="person__item">J</article>
  <article data-index="K" class="person__item">K</article>
  <article data-index="L" class="person__item">L</article>
  <article data-index="M" class="person__item">M...</article>
  <article data-index="N" class="person__item">N...</article>
  <article data-index="O" class="person__item">O...</article>
  <article data-index="P" class="person__item">P...</article>
  <article data-index="Q" class="person__item">Q...</article>
  <article data-index="R" class="person__item">R...</article>
  <article data-index="S" class="person__item">S...</article>
  <article data-index="T" class="person__item">T...</article>
  <article data-index="U" class="person__item">U...</article>
  <article data-index="V" class="person__item">V...</article>
  <article data-index="W" class="person__item">W...</article>
  <article data-index="X" class="person__item">X...</article>
  <article data-index="Y" class="person__item">Y...</article>
  <article data-index="Z" class="person__item">Z...</article>
</section>


<div id="index">A</div>
<div id="line"></div>
```

*edit: I ended up finding another way to get an element near or under the cursor, in spite of the "margin" problem. But it's not any simpler and I'm not sure if it's really better. It uses [caretRangeFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/caretPositionFromPoint).

```
  var el;
  var rng = document.caretRangeFromPoint(window.innerWidth / 2, 0);
  //console.log(rng);
  if (rng) {
    el = rng.startContainer;
    if (!(el instanceof Element)) el = el.parentElement;
    el = el.closest('article');
  }
```